# Symfony with Bootstrap - Radio style button toggling

Tags: symfony

With Form class and Bootstrap 4 Form theme, how render radio style button toggling ?

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

Link : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In your src/Form/Type/File_nameType.php file:

```
$builder
    ->add('your label name', Radio::class, array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-group btn-group-toggle')
       ))
```

Then in twig template you can add label class too:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Your name', {
       'label_attr': {'class': 'btn btn-secondary active'}
}) }}
```

Comment: Thanks and with ChoiceType, it's possible ?

Comment: In the official documentation about, https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/forms/types/choice.html, attr option appears within Inherited options.

Comment: But for option "choices" ?

Comment: You have choice_attr for that: https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr